# Creating a new type that cannot be substituted by the base type

Tags: types, casting, typescript

In TypeScript, I can create a type named `UnitCount` as an alias of `number`:

```
type UnitCount = number;
```

If I now define a function that takes a parameter of this type, I can call the function with either a `UnitCount` or a `number`:

```
function test(units: UnitCount) {
    console.log('units =', units);
}

test(1 as UnitCount); // correct
test(2); // also correct
```

Is there any way to define `UnitCount` such that a `number` cannot be used in the place of a `UnitCount` without an explicit cast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since TypeScript uses structural typing you have to find a way to differentiate the types structurally.

One way is to use a "[brand](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/202#issuecomment-142144357)" that extends `Number` and adds an unused property to the type... unfortunately using it requires an assertion to `any`:

```
interface UnitCount extends Number {
    _unitCountBrand: any;
}

function test(units: UnitCount) {
    console.log('units =', units);
}

test(1 as any); // ok
test(2); // error
```

This assertion can be abstracted away into a function, which is a little nicer:

```
function toUnitCount(val: number) {
    return val as any as UnitCount;
}

test(toUnitCount(1)); // ok
test(2); // error
```

Note there is currently some discussion on [supporting nominal types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/202) and [units of measure](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/364).

Comment: Great, thanks, this works. It's so hacky though, I wish there was support for this in the language.

Comment: @rid yeah, it's definitely hacky. I wish there was support as well!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to define an interface with a numeric field:

```
interface UnitCount {
  value: number;
}
```